# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY or sObject type 'Lead' is not supported when calling describeSoqlListViews over SOAP

Tags: soap-api, list-view, describes

This is a bit of an unusual one. I'v generated Apex classes using WSDL2Apex in Salesforce itself, using Salesforce's Tooling API WSDL file (had to modify it a bit - there's no `ANY` type in SF).

Then I wrote this little class:

```
public with sharing class SoapListViewDescribe {
    public static void getOne(String view, String sobjectString){
        toolingSoapSforceCom.DescribeSoqlListViewParams params = new toolingSoapSforceCom.DescribeSoqlListViewParams();
        params.developerNameOrId = view;
        params.sobjectType = sobjectString;
        toolingSoapSforceCom.DescribeSoqlListViewsRequest request = new toolingSoapSforceCom.DescribeSoqlListViewsRequest();
        request.listViewParams = new toolingSoapSforceCom.DescribeSoqlListViewParams[]{ params };
        toolingSoapSforceCom.SforceService service = new toolingSoapSforceCom.SforceService();
        service.SessionHeader = new toolingSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = 'someSID';
        service.CallOptions = new toolingSoapSforceCom.CallOptions_element();
        service.CallOptions.client = 'ournamespace/ournamespace/';
        service.timeout_x = 60 * 1000;
        service.endpoint_x = Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/T/45.0';
        toolingSoapSforceCom.DescribeSoqlListViewResult resp = service.describeSoqlListViews(request);
        System.debug(resp);
    }
}
```

When called upon Lead object I get error (either by view name or Id):

> INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'Lead' is not supported in describeSoqlListViews.

When called on our custom object, I get error:

> INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id

When called on custom object by view Id

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: List view not found.

Comment: Solved it myself. Turns out I needed to use `executeListView`.

Comment: Want to post your own answer so folks can identify it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself, I needed to use `executeListView` method instead of describe.